# Debug `Unexpected end of JSON input Error` on content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

I am having this very strange bug where my fetch function won't work on my content script but works from my popup page.

The error that I am getting is `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

I also tried Incognito mode with other extensions disabled but that didn't do anything.

However, it's fully working on my Brave browser.

```
const getRequest = function (url) {
  return window.fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Do you get `true` in the console if you replace `.then(res => res.json())` by `.then(res => res.text()).then((text) => console.log(["\u2028", "\u2029"].some((char) => text.includes(char))))`? If so, `.text()` it first, then replace these characters, then use `JSON.parse`. See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-superset.

Comment: I got false @Xufox

Comment: Okay, then it’s not this Unicode issue. Does a simple `.then((res) => res.text()).then(console.log)` reveal anything insightful?

Comment: no, nothing, just blank

Comment: Then, it seems, the response is empty.

Comment: Inspect the request, its response body and its headers in devtools. So far though it sounds like a bug in Chrome, which you can verify by trying in a much older portable version.

Comment: I had a working extension in the Chrome Web Store that now gets this very same error in the latest version of Chrome. I have no idea why yet, but will let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross-origin fetches (CORS) is no longer allowed in Chrome Web Extensions (content scripts). The request will go through, but the response body will always be empty, which is why you are getting an error when trying to parse to JSON.

> To improve security, cross-origin fetches will soon be disallowed from
>   content scripts in Chrome Extensions.  Such requests can be made from
>   extension background pages instead, and relayed to content scripts
>   when needed.

See: [Changes to Cross-Origin Requests in Chrome Extension Content Scripts](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches)

> When cross-origin fetches are needed, perform them from the extension
>   background page rather than in the content script.  Relay the response
>   to the content scripts as needed (e.g., using extension messaging
>   APIs). For example:

Old content script, making a cross-origin fetch:

```
var itemId = 12345;
var url = "https://another-site.com/price-query?itemId=" +
         encodeURIComponent(request.itemId);
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => parsePrice(text))
  .then(price => ...)
  .catch(error => ...)
```

New content script, asking its background page to fetch the data instead:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {contentScriptQuery: "queryPrice", itemId: 12345},
    price => ...);
```

New extension background page, fetching from a known URL and relaying data:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.contentScriptQuery == "queryPrice") {
      var url = "https://another-site.com/price-query?itemId=" +
              encodeURIComponent(request.itemId);
      fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(text => parsePrice(text))
          .then(price => sendResponse(price))
          .catch(error => ...)
      return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
  });
```