# Why chrome extension javascript ajax call not returning json data on success while calling yii2 action?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-extension, yii2

I'm trying to call PHP Yii 2.0 action using AJAX call which suppose to return JSON data. On success of AJAX call no data is coming. Earlier It was working, how to fix this?

This was working on older Google-chrome versions, don't know exactly from which version it stopped working. First it stopped working in Ubuntu google chrome then in Windows operating system google chrome (I'm using latest version of google chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 64-bit).

Yii2 PHP code:

```
public function actionChromeJsonResponse(){
$a['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $a['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    return json_encode($a);
}
```

Chrome extension Javascript code:

```
var name = 'Ankit';
var email = 'ankit.bakshi1@gmail.com';
var save_response = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://www.abc.in/site/chrome-json-response";
var params = ('name='+name+'&email='+email);
save_response.open("POST", url, true);

save_response.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
save_response.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(save_response.readyState == 4 && save_response.status == 200) {
        var result = save_response.responseText;
        console.log(result);
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(result);
    }
}
save_response.send(params);
```

Comment: If this is inside a content script, see [CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) for more info and solutions.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you make a canonical Q&A for this (or if you know a canonical question, can you link it?)

Comment: Urgh... maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55443968) can serve as a base.

Comment: @wOxxOm what you have suggested is Message passing API, So there is no way through Javascript ajax call ?

Comment: If this is indeed a CORB issue, there are no other solutions except those listed in the explainer document.